# GCE Automation Script Not Working to run Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created an instance in `Google Cloud Compute Engine (Debian OS)` to host a `Spring Boot Maven Application`. I installed `maven`.Now while configuring the instance I added below script in the *automation startup* box -

```
cd spring-boot-app/
mvn clean package
cd target/
nohup java -jar artifact-1.0.jar &
```

I used `nohup` and `&` to run the application in background.

Now when I stop then start/resume the instance and open terminal through `SSH` & run the following command -

`ps ax | grep java`

I don't see my app running. What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you sure that the best platform to run your spring boot app? What's the type of application?

Answer (score 0):

When monitoring the logs, I found this -

`cd spring-boot-app/ directory does not exists`

So I realized that the script is being executed in the root directory. And when I connected to the terminal using `SSH` in `Google Cloud Compute Engine VM` I was redirected to `home` directory of my `username`.

Thus by updating the script I was able to run the startup script.

```
cd home/{username}/
cd spring-boot-app/
mvn clean package
cd target/
nohup java -jar artifact-1.0.jar &
```